# Transaction state - data type - from string to number conversion - using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I know that technically
`Fabric` stores key-value pairs in which the key is a string, and the value is a byte array.

How can I use the `Number` data type only in transaction code for comparison purposes? I'm guessing that in practice everything is stored in string?

I want to check if new `num` value is greater than `x` value already written to the ledger, `parseInt` does not seem to work.

```js
async transaction(ctx, id, num){
     const x = await ctx.stub.getState(id);

     if(parseInt(x, 10) > parseInt(num, 10)) {
         // then something
     }
}
```

edit: SOLVED, It turned out that the comparison works normally when I called my transaction from client app using `fabric-network` API, however error persist while using CLI of `@worldsibu/hurley`.

Comment: The parseInt() method is probably working, have you checked what the value of 'x' and 'num' are when debugging? Odds are they aren't being set or set to what you think they should be.

Comment: PS. I am using ```@worldsibu/hurley``` npm package to set up my network and test my transations logic from CLI. Yes the values are sent as string because everything works when I simple assign them without parsing and comparing.

Comment: Can you share what's being passed into the method when you test it? Like a snapshot of what 'x' and 'num' is when you place a breakpoint on the if block line

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly mentioned that the value in HLF is stored as a byte Array, you just missed out the step of converting byteArray to string before your comparison. Try this:

```
const xAsString = x.toString();
if(parseInt(xAsString, 10) > parseInt(num, 10)) {
     // then something
 }
```

I am also considering that you just stored only a number in the state, if not so then extract the number from the string and then do the needed comparison.